# creating exe file by pyinstaller but doesn't work

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I need to convert "myfile.py" file to "myfile.exe" but when I try to do this, the "myfile.exe" appears in the `dist` folder and immediately disappears after.

Comment: The antivirus in your system might be deleting `.exe` file. Check by disabling your antivirus for a while.

Comment: Can you give us the exact method you are using to convert it?

Comment: thank for your response, I cannot get your words exactly. but I used pycharm to write my codes and powershell to create .exe file by pyinstaller library. additionally, my codes have input command so it should not disappear suddenly.....

Comment: @Erfan can you give us the exact command you are using from powershell?